# How to implement dynamic role based actions authorization using meteor at server side?

Tags: meteor

I have an application where in which I can create multiple dynamic roles.
And I can also assign each role a set of actions in which each action turns out to be a publisher/method at server side. 
In this context can I user meteor-roles by alanning ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is check a user is in a role before you proceed with a publication or a method.

Publication example:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';
import { Posts } from '/imports/api/posts/posts';

Meteor.publish('publicationName', function() {
    if(!Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'administrator')) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('unauthorised', 'You cannot do this.');
    }

    return Posts.find();
});
```

Method example:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';
import { Posts } from '/imports/api/posts/posts';

Meteor.methods({
    'remove.post':(id) => {
        if(!Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'administrator')) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('unauthorised', 'You cannot do this.');
        }

        return Posts.remove(id);
    }
});
```